# Add an expand and collapse image to a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

It works when I click the link, it collapses the other hidden names, but I'm trying to have an image changing once the link is clicked. Can't get this one to work. Here is what I have now:

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {


       $(".toggler").click(function(e) {

         e.preventDefault();

         //the data stored in the data-emails
         var emailData = ($(this).attr("data-emails"));

         //toggle the link clicked on
         $(".email" + emailData).toggle();

         $(".more").toggle();

         //select the parent and find the span so you can
         //toggle the "email-plus" class

         $(this).parent().find("span").toggleClass("email-plus");

         $(this).parent().find("span").toggleClass("less");


       });

     });
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">

  <tr style="vertical-align: bottom">
    <td>
      Names:
      <a href="#" class="toggler" data-emails="1">
        <span class="email-plus" style="text-transform: none;font-weight: bold;outline: 0;">All Names</span>
        <span class="more"><img src='more.png'></span>  <span class="less"><img src='less.png'></span>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="vertical-align: top;display:none;" class="email1">
    <td colspan="6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="vertical-align: top;">
      <p class="email1" style="display:none;font-weight: bold; margin-left: 44px; margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 3px;">Name 1</p>
      <p class="email1" style="display:none;font-weight: bold; margin-left: 44px; margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 3px;">Name 2</p>
      <p class="email1" style="display:none;font-weight: bold; margin-left: 44px; margin-top: 1px; margin-bottom: 2px;">Name 3</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854648/changing-image-src-for-expand-collapse-function-jq-or-js

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635378/toggle-images-for-expand-all-and-collapse-all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the demo please and try it.Remove `more` and `less`.

http://jsfiddle.net/tvd2dfe0/2/